# Group policy to disable auto-disconnect

Tags: windows, network-share

Several drives mapped via GPO keep on disconnecting.
After some googeling I found the feature (more like a bug in my network...) that auto-disconnects active shares after 15 minutes.

I realize that the `net config server` command solves this issue for a local computer, but I'd like to apply it to the entire network via group policy.

Currently it seems like I'll have to change registry keys manually with this group policy.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Your proposal works on the server side: you don't need to run the command on every client computer.

```
net config server /autodisconnect:-1
```

Where the number is timeout in minutes from 0 to 65,535 and -1 for disabled.

For client side you can [Configure a Registry Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753092.aspx) via GPO, namely [`KeepConn`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960471.aspx),

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters]
"KeepConn"=dword:0000ffff
```

> Specifies the maximum amount of time that an idle connection can
>   remain open. If the idle time for a connection reaches the value of
>   this entry, the connection is closed. Increase the value of this entry
>   if your application closes and opens Universal Naming Convention (UNC)
>   files on a server less frequently than every 10 minutes. This
>   decreases the number of reconnections to a server.

However, there isn't more direct way to do this via GP.

Some have reported that there's less problems with drives mapped with a `net use` command during logon scripts than with the ones mapped in GPO, but I wouldn't make any major changed based on that, as using GPO Drive Mappings is way more maintainable.

Comment: Can you refer to any articles about the gpo mapping vs script mapping?

Answer (score -2):

The best way would be to create logon scripts using the "net use" command and executing them on startup. Simply create your batch file, put it in the sysvol\scripts folder and call it in the "Logon script" property of the user in the AD(see screenshot). You'll see that they won't get disconnected anymore. Also keep in mind you can use wildcards such as %USERNAME% in your batch file, so you don't have to create a different logon script for each user if you want to map a personal folder.

P.S.
Don't use logon scripts for your Administrator account... This is just an example :)

[image: Logon script]

Comment: While this may work for simple configurations, large organizations might have more specific needs. Using Group Policy Drive Mappings is way more flexible and maintainable than creating several personal login scripts for every need. With GP, for instance, it's possible to [Map Drives Based on Group Membership](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership/), both _inclusively_ and _exclusively_; mappings are automatically changed on group membership change. Therefore, this doesn't actually _answer_ the question.